# GridView in asp.net not accepting click

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an issue, one of those simple basics, but just do not know about its behavior. I have a simple GridView displaying on an asp.net page using VS 2010.  The page loads fine and I can see the Grid but when I try to click on it, nothing happens.  It's like clicking on an empty space.  Just trying to send any row data to a TextBox.

FYI:

1) The GridView is being filled out from a DataAdapter and its own DataSet.

2) The OnSelectedIndexChanged event has been set up.

3) Every field is bound to its specific field from the DB.

GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" Width="300px" Height="100px" ID="mstPx_grdCtrl" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" onselectedindexchanged="mstPx_grdCtrl_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="codPx" HeaderText="Código" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre" HeaderText="NOMBRE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="apellido" HeaderText="APELLIDO" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# Code Behind:  you can see both options I have tried...

```
protected void mstPx_grdCtrl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtId.Text = mstPx_grdCtrl.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    txtId.Text = mstPx_grdCtrl.Rows[mstPx_grdCtrl.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the line `txtId.Text = mstPx_grdCtrl.Rows[mstPx_grdCtrl.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;` and make sure that it is getting executed and it has such a cell?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this property on the aspx file

```
AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
```

take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onselectedindexchanged.aspx

or you could use a

```
<asp:ButtonField DataTextField="code" />
```

and then define the onclick function for that field to do you what you want

Comment: Kuba, thanks for suggested solution. Still not getting info from row clicked. I have tried the (AutoGenerateSelectButton="True") before but I do not think the issue would be because of that. About the (ButtonField) for some reason it´s not been recognized by the visual as an asp control. Is that ButtonField a control outside the GridView ???, just double checking...greetings